# getting first column blank postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT CASE WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 3 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm' 
            WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 15 AND 18 THEN '3pm-6pm' END "time window",COUNT(*) FROM tickets where created_at < now()
GROUP BY  CASE WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 3 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm' WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 15 AND 18 THEN '3pm-6pm' END;

 time window | count 
-------------+-------
             |     6
 9am-3pm     |    69
```

is it possible to filter it by date  along with time so that my result set will looks like

```
Date        | time window | count 
------------+-------------+-------
12-01-2020  |      9am-3pm|     6
12-01-2020  |      3pm-6pm|    69
13-01-2020  |      9am-3pm|    12
13-01-2020  |      3pm-6pm|    14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can handle this requirement using a calendar table approach:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '12-01-2020' AS created_at UNION ALL
    SELECT '13-01-2020'
),
tw AS (
    SELECT '9am-3pm' AS "time window" UNION ALL
    SELECT '3pm-6pm'
),
cte AS (
    SELECT
        created_at::date AS created_at,
        CASE WHEN DATE_PART('hour', created_at) BETWEEN 3 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm'
             WHEN DATE_PART('hour', created_at) BETWEEN 15 AND 18 THEN '3pm-6pm' END "time window",
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tickets
    WHERE created_at < NOW()
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)

SELECT
    d.created_at,
    tw."time window",
    COALESCE(t.cnt, 0) AS count
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN tw
LEFT JOIN cte t
    ON d.created_at = t.created_at AND tw."time window" = t."time window"
ORDER BY
    d.dt,
    tw."time window";
```

Comment: looking for same query as return by me : 
```
SELECT CASE WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 3 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm' 
            WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 15 AND 18 THEN '3pm-6pm' END "time window",COUNT(*) FROM tickets where created_at < now()
GROUP BY  CASE WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 3 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm' WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 15 AND 18 THEN '3pm-6pm' END;
```

it is fine if there is no date column main thing is time window and count

Answer (score 0):

You are actually asking two questions:

- The "empty space" (really an SQL NULL) is there because there are dates that do not fall within any of the time ranges. You can exclude them with an additional `WHERE` condition.
- To get the date part as well, add

  ```
  CAST (created_at AS date)
  ```

  to the `SELECT` list and the `GROUP BY` ckause.

Comment: Note that this approach might result in missing dates/slots should the OP's table have no data there.